# SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Permission denied Is the server running on host “…” and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

Tengo un sistema de información desarrollado en Laravel con un servidor de base de datos en Postgresql. El servidor web y de bases de datos están en la misma subred. Ambos servidores con S.O Red Hat Enterprise Linux.

Al momento de ingresar se presenta el siguiente error:

> SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Permission denied Is
>   the server running on host "10.0.4.127" and accepting TCP/IP
>   connections on port 5432?

Funciona conectarnos al servidor de Postgresql usando "psql", a través de pgAdmin y al momento de realizar las migraciones y seeders se ejecutan perfectamente.

Se ha intentado solucionar con las siguientes operaciones y no se soluciona el error: • Se configuró la línea: `listen_addresses = '*'` en el archivo`postgresql.conf` • Se agregó está línea al archivo `pg_hba.conf: host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5`• También se intentó con otra aplicación más sencilla y salía exactamente el mismo error.

¿Qué me recomiendan realizar para solucionar este problema?

Comment: Reinicias el servidor luego de hacer esos cambios?

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez Sí, ya se reinició el servidor.

Comment: que sistema operativo usas?

Comment: Secundo a @IgmerRodriguez que SO estas utilizando?

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez, Red Hat Enterprise Linux.

Comment: @DrakoRod Red Hat Enterprise Linux

Comment: prueba desabilitando el firewall `systemctl stop firewalld`

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez Ya se probó con deshabilitando el firewall según tu indicación y tampoco funcionó.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al ser un SO  Red Hat Enterprise Linux probablemente la seguridad del SELinux puede ser que este bloqueando o no permita que te conectes, puedes configurarlo de la siguiente manera para permitir eso.

```
service httpd stop
service postgresql stop
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
service httpd start
service postgresql start
```

Saludos!

Comment: Se ha dado solución al problema, muchas gracias!!